# Heap corruption when using delete

Tags: c++

I have a `MultiString` class that has some methods in it.

I am strugling with deleting my array of strings in the destructor, I get heap corruption.

Here is my class (some methods are cut)

```cpp
class MultiString {
public:
    //constructor destructor
    MultiString(int);
    ~MultiString();

    //methods
    void Setat(int nindex, const char* str);

    //attributes

    char** buf;//pointer to vector
    int str_nmb;//strings number
};
```

Constructor code:

```cpp
MultiString::MultiString(int number)
{
    str_nmb = number;
    buf = new char* [number];
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) buf[i] = NULL;
}
```

Setat code (used to set strings in array):

```cpp
void MultiString::Setat(int nindex, const char* str)
{
    if (nindex<0 || nindex>str_nmb || str == NULL) {
        std::cout << "gg";
        return;
    }
    char* tmp = new char[strlen(str)+1];
    if (tmp == NULL) return;
    if (buf[nindex] != NULL) delete buf[nindex]; //here delete works fine
    buf[nindex] = tmp;
    strcpy_s(buf[nindex], strlen(buf[nindex]), str);
    std::cout << buf[nindex]<< std::endl;
}
```

Destructor code:

```cpp
MultiString::~MultiString()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < str_nmb; i++)
         delete buf[i]; // heap corruption here
    delete buf;
}
```

And my `main()`:

```cpp
int main()
{
    MultiString* ms = new MultiString(3);
    ms->etat(0, "qwerty");
    ms->Setat(1, "asdfgh");
    ms->Setat(2, "zxcvbn");
    delete ms;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strlen(buf[nindex])` is wrong in your `strpy_s` operation. There is no there-there yet. That should be `strlen(str)+1` . Unrelated, `nindex>str_nmb` should be `nindex>=str_nmb` in your range check. And *all* of your `delete` operations except the one in `main` should be using `delete[]`, since all of their matching `new` operations are using `new[]`.

Comment: Use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) and use much more C++ [containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) and [std::string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string)

Comment: The call of `strcpy_s(buf[nindex], strlen(buf[nindex]), str);` calls `strlen(buf[nindex])` before any data has been copied to `buf[nindex]`.    The behaviour is therefore undefined.   You probably intend to use `strlen(str)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```cpp
char* tmp = new char[strlen(str)+1];
// ...
buf[nindex] = tmp;
strcpy_s(buf[nindex], strlen(buf[nindex]), str);
```

`buf[nindex]` points to the freshly allocated, but **uninitialized** memory area.  Calling `strlen` on that is undefined behavior and likely what corrupts your heap.  You probably want to call `strlen(str)` instead.

---

Apart from that you're making a few other mistakes:

- Rule of 0/3/5 broken.
- `delete` where `delete[]` would be necessary
- Wrong bounds check (`nindex>str_nmb`)
- What about `Multistring(-5)` ?
- `if (tmp == NULL) return;` ... no, you shouldn't *mute* errors. Throw an exception or something.

Also .. why `strcpy_s` ? Use `std::strncpy` ... that's at least guaranteed to be available! Make sure the copied C string is null terminated!